# It is possible from generated uuid3 recive name?

Tags: python, uuid

I use:

```
    uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, "TestName")
```

and I get `uuid`.

Is it possible from generated uuid3 to get `"TestName"`?

Comment: if you accumulate this information, yes, otherwise no

Comment: how to accumulate this information?

Comment: mount and feed a table in a database for instance

Comment: create for examples key dict with {UUID:name,UUID1:name1,...}?